# Gatling - having a randomSwitch inside a repeat

Tags: repeat, gatling

I am trying to get a randomSwitch to serve me a random function and I'd like to have that inside a .repeat so that I can iterate on that.

Code example:

```
    val scn = scenario("myScenario").repeat(20) {
                                       randomSwitch(50.0 -> function1,
                                                     50.0 -> function2)
    }
```

The randomSwitch part is working on itself but when placed inside a repeat it's throwing:

```
found   : io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
required: io.gatling.core.session.Expression[Int]
```

I would be grateful for any tips on how I could get this behavior to work even if in a different form.

Comment: The sample you provided compiles perfectly fine. There must be some other typo on your side.

Answer (score 0):

`function1` and `function2` should be of type `ChainBuilder` (constructed with `exec(...)`) and not of any other type.